# Embedding javascript in php pages

Tags: php

I am trying to embed some JavaScript into a php page with the intention of getting Jquery to work. The php is in a wordpress site. This will eventually form the basis of a plugin. I have used `<script>` tags to embed a call to an alert function, which does work well. Problem is if I try to add some jquery code e.g `$(document).ready(function(){});` it doesn't work, any consequent alerts don't work, no errors or anything!

I've tried googling the problem and there's loads of advice but nothing is working

```
echo "<script>alert('This works')</script>"

echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

alert('But this doesn't');});
</script>"
```

The first alert appears fine, but the second doesn't.

Comment: `alert('This works')` must need `<script>`

Comment: in php page, it will as its working in html pages `<script>alert(1)</script>`

Comment: Double quoted strings are parsed in PHP. It this case PHP is trying to replace jQuery $ to PHP variable. Change to single quoted string.

Comment: @WebHQ: agreed , and he also having issue with first alert as he is not terminating.

Comment: did u checked @banjoquint

Comment: This is worst practice ever :-D But why just not put JS in multi-line string?
`echo <<< EOT\n<script>alert("somestring");\n$(document).ready(/* ... */);\nEOT`
I havn't test it, but this may work. Just replace \n with actual new lines.

Comment: Also, are you sure jQuery is loading?

Comment: did u checked both solutions

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have 2 issues, first of all, you are not terminating your first alert:

```
echo "alert('This works')"
```

you must need to terminate with `;` otherwise it will give you `javascript` error.

**Second,** in your second alert you have quotation issue, you are using single quote inside a single quotes.:

```
alert('But this doesn't'); // remove single quotation from here.
```

**I tried this and its working fine:**

```
echo "alert('This works');"; // terminate the first line
echo "$(document).ready(function(){
alert('But this does not'); 
});";
```

Comment: JS doesn't need semicolons

Comment: @Miken32 u r right but u echo both together u will get an error in console plz try

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad codding. You should separate logic and view layers into script and template files.

But if you have no other option try Heredoc strings:

```
echo <<<EOT
<script>
    $(function() {
        alert("this will work with > ' < char included");
        alert('this will work with > \' < char included');
        alert('this will work with');
        alert("this will work with");
    });
</script>
EOT;
```